# JDK-BUG Java validate xml with Validator ID issue

Tags: validation, xsd, schema

I use javax.xml.validation.Validator to validate xml files. While in xsd an element has ID attribute like below:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
```

When validating, In DOMResultBuilder class line 255,

```
((ElementImpl) elem).setIdAttributeNode (attr, true);
```

this line execute, then to ElementImpl class line 948, when executing:

```
if (at.getOwnerElement() != this) {}
```

this will cause the error:
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
It is because "at.getOwnerElement()" will return null, but how could this happen? 
My xml like below:

```
<cp:ruleset>
     <cp:rule id="rule_cdiv_00">
     </cp:rule>
</cp:ruleset>
```

Thanks very much for any advice.

//added 18 Jun
Now I know it's a bug in jdk8, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.DOMResultBuilder,link as below:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1212

But how can I fix it in my project?

Comment: Thanks for supplying the line numbers, but without all of the code they do not help very much. I think you will need to cut down your scenario and create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I find it a bug record here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1212